# Text Spacing In Recursive Function Which Prints A Star Pattern

Tags: c#, recursion

I am trying to solve an exercise on recursion. The exercise is to be solved in C but for ease I'm first trying to solve it in C# (where I'm more accustomed to). It says:

> Write a program where a user must enter a positive number n which is a
>   power of 2 ( I think that 2^0 = 1 must be excluded even if it doesn't clarify that) and then print a specific pattern with the help of a
>   recursive function.
>
> Example for n = 8 , notice that the middle line has 8 stars:

```
       * (7 spaces)
      ** (6 spaces)
      *  (6 spaces)
    **** (4 spaces)
     *   (5 spaces)
    **   (4 spaces)
    *    (4 spaces)
******** (0 spaces)
   *     (3 spaces)
  **     (2 spaces)
  *      (2 spaces)
****     (0 spaces)
 *       (1 space)
**       (0 spaces)
*        (0 spaces)
```

> Example for n = 4 :

```
   * (3 spaces)
  ** (2 spaces)
  *  (2 spaces)
**** (0 spaces)
 *   (1 space)
**   (0 spaces)
*    (0 spaces)
```

I have translated the exercise from Greek so I'm sorry in advance if I have phrased something wrong. I have personally added the required spacing each line must have to make it more easy for you.

**What I have done:**

I have found the structure of the recursive function which is ( I post the whole code of my program):

```
static void Main()
{
    int n;
    do
    {
       n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    }
    while (!IsPowerOf2(n)) ;
    PrintRecursive(n);
}

static void PrintRecursive(int stars)
{
    if (stars > 2)
    {
        PrintRecursive(stars / 2);
        Console.WriteLine(new string(' ',0) + new string('*', stars));
        PrintRecursive(stars / 2);
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine(new string(' ', 0) + "*");
        Console.WriteLine(new string(' ', 0) + "**");
        Console.WriteLine(new string(' ', 0) + "*");
    }
}

static bool IsPowerOf2(int n)
{
    return (n != 0) && ((n & (n - 1)) == 0);
}
```

This recursive function produces the correct sequence of stars for each acceptable n (except from 1 which I insist that it must be excluded).

**What I haven't done:**

I really can't find a formula to calculate the spacing required in each Console.WriteLine() . To get the exact correct format of the pattern, I must find something to replace the count parameter in the instances of the String Class I initiate.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, I think you should have your function have two arguments `int stars` and `int spacing` which is calculated as `spacing` for the first recursive invocation and `spacing + stars / 2` for the second one (or something very similar)

Comment: I have not really understood what do you mean with a _star pattern_ Can you add to your question an example of the output expected?

Comment: @Steve I have added an example.

Comment: I'm also not sure I understand the requirement. What exactly is the pattern? What are the rules for displaying the stars and the spaces?

Comment: @someone I have thought of the spacing parameter but still I can't find the correct formula. When I posted the code I removed that parameter because I can't find a way for it to work and wanted the code to be clean on posting.

Comment: NickDelta: I've got it to work with that but I had to replace the `if(stars > 2)` condition with `if(stars > 1)` and handle the case for 1 (`Console.WriteLine(new string(' ', spacing) + "*");`)

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed The exercise is not well defined I understand that but that's not my fault. However, I have understood what it asks. I'm going to add more examples to make it more understandable.

Comment: @someone Post code as an answer please

Comment: It might be just me but the pattern is really not clear. For example, if your input is 32, you get the star pattern of `(1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 8, 1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 16, 1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 8, 1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 32,...)` Is that what's expected? Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, what you are looking for is this. With your Power of two handling.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        PrintStars(8, 0, 0);
    }

    static void PrintStars(int stars, int prefix, int suffix)
    {
        if(stars == 1)
        {
            PrintStarsToConsole(stars, prefix, suffix);
            return;
        }
        var halfStars = stars >> 1;
        PrintStars(halfStars, prefix + halfStars, suffix); // for n = 4: __**
        PrintStarsToConsole(stars, prefix, suffix);        // for n = 4: ****
        PrintStars(halfStars, prefix, suffix + halfStars); // for n = 4: **__
    }

    static void PrintStarsToConsole(int stars, int prefix, int suffix)
    {
        Console.Write(new string(' ', prefix));
        Console.Write(new string('*', stars));
        Console.Write(new string(' ', suffix));
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking, great answer !

Comment: You can ignore the suffix handling if you do not care about the ending spaces. But I think it makes the algorithm more readable like that.